# drag_and_drop failing with timeout error

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to implement drag and drop functionality using Selenium WebDriver with Ruby. In order to achieve that I did following:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

driver.get "myurl"

source = driver.find_element(:id, '19026240')
target = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@id='rootLabelChildren']/div/div")

driver.action.drag_and_drop(source, target).perform
```

This doesn't result into any error like unable to locate element, element not attached to DOM etc. But this is resulting into timeout error:

```
Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rbuf_fill'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1319:in `block in transport_request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `catch'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `transport_request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1286:in `block in request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83:in `response_for
'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:629:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:607:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:394:in `mouseMoveTo'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/mouse.rb:54:in `move_to'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:344:in `block in
perform'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:343:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:343:in `perform'
        from (irb):6
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'irb(main):007:0> end
SyntaxError: (irb):7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Manually, drag and drop works properly. What could be the reason of time out error?

Firefox version: 21
Selenium WebDriver: 2.33.0

HTML code:

For target

```
<div id="rootLabelChildren" class="children">
<div class="label " labelid="74ce292d65844af7b4e480782d8e9b38" labelname="0106">
<div class="labelName terminal" draggable="true">0106</div>
<div class="children"> </div>
</div>
```

For source

```
<table class="dataGridHeader">
<div class="dataGridScrollbarContainer scrollable" style="">
<div class="dataGridContents" style="min-height: 12880px;">
<table class="buffer" style="margin-top: 0px;">
<tbody>
<tr id="19026240" class="selected" draggable="true">
```

Comment: The id `19026240` seems like a dynamic one. Try using a different selector, xpath or css selectors perhaps.

Comment: give us the full code,with the firefox version and selenium-webdriver version.

Comment: No, id is not dynamic.

Comment: @Priti Updated question details according to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [**CHANGELOG**](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG)

*Selenium WebDriver: 2.33.0* doesn't support *Firefox version: 21*. So downgrade it to *Firefox version: 19* or *Firefox version: 20*.

This will handle the error : `rescue in rbuf_fill`.

To drag and drop the element try the below:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "myurl"
source = driver.find_element(:css, 'tr#19026240')
target = driver.find_element(:css, 'div#rootLabelChildren>div>div')
driver.action.drag_and_drop(source, target).perform
```

For your *Drag and Drop* functionality I got a good link [**HTML5 Drag and Drop with Selenium Webdriver**](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=3604). It will help you out.

Comment: But drag and drop functionality working for another tests with same browser version and selenium webdriver version.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Before that I wanted to make sure that I'm not wrong at my code.

Comment: Downgraded Firefox to 20.0.1 but actual drag and drop action isn't happening. Now, it's returning 'nil' This is also happening with the test which was working with Firefox 21

Comment: Looks something wrong, I'm using. I tried xpath=//table[@class='buffer']//tr for source still drag and drop not happening.

Comment: @TDHM So now you are not getting the time out errors..right ? Now I will help you for your other issue.. give me some times..I am middle of my some works..

Comment: Priti, when I used driver.find_element(:css, 'tr#19026240') it's giving error: An invalid or illegal string was specified. And if I use driver.find_element(:css, 'tr#hi') I get 'Unable to locate element' error. Looks in css integers  aren't accepted hence error while using css as 'tr#19026240'